# autohotkey: unable to send numbers as integers (sends like a string)

Tags: autohotkey

```
6::
send 6
return
```

also tried

```
$6::send 6 return
$3::send 3 return
$5::send 3 return
```

Nor did blind or text or replacing send with any of the other sendmode names on the send doc page achieve the effect, which is, for a game to recognize these sends as numbers. These work while typing in chatbox ingame, i.e. `"hello14674355"`, but not when selecting from a menu that use integers, i.e. `"press a number from 1-9 to activate an option in a menu"`. I need ideas/help on what else i can try or do to get this to work. I have a situation where some numbered keys are hotkeys on certain condition (when im not typing for ex), this requires I manually setup the condition where they do send their own value. I need a fix for that. Is there way to retain their normal function as default, but check it only after the hotkey behaviour conditions? When they r in hitkey mode i need them to not send their own value but the hotkey.
Can I get `~3:: if(){...` to work infront of 3's native function? then i can return early maybe so it doesnt proc the native 3 sending?

Comment: Can you give us more details on which software/ game you are using this with so that we can test?

Comment: id Tech 3 engine, games from 2004~ish.

Comment: Nothing you send is either string or number, that's what humans see. In fact what is behind is a [Scan Code](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm). If you show the full code perhaps there's an issue there.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by show my full code. The OP is my full code. 6::
send 6
return